# Python - Catch signals and exceptions in remote script

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, exception, signals

I am running a remote Python script on AWS (EC2 ubuntu) in background. The script performs some file manipulations, launches a long running simulation (subprocess run with `os.system(...)`) and writes some log files. I would like to manage the status of the running script and hopefully exit gracefully from various conditions. Specifically:

1. The **sub-process** is interrupted by the user with signal 15.
2. The simulation (**sub-process**) fails (signal 8 - Floating point exception)
3. The vm is rebooted
4. The vm is terminated. I am using Elastic File System, so even if the instance is destroyed, all the files are not.

I know how to handle basic exceptions, but I am a bit lost when I need to catch exceptions from subprocesses. Can you recommend a solid approach?

EDIT: Please notice the bold part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your given scenarios, try with signal handling. In given cases, case 1 (**signal 15**) and case 3 (**vm is getting rebooted**), are similar(generally **signal 15/SIGTERM** is part of shutdown sequence or maybe triggered by user with proper privileges. Nonetheless it serves the required purpose).
signal 8 - SIGFPE

```
import signal

def signalHandler(sigNum, frameObject):
    if sigNum == 15:
       # Code for handling signal 15 goes here
    elif sigNum == 8:
       # Code for handling signal 8 goes here

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signalHandler) # signal 15
signal.signal(signal.SIGFPE, signalHandler)  # signal 8
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me to understand, but in this way I cannot handle the signals to the sub-process. If the sub-process is killed, the Python script just thinks that it is completed and it goes to the next line. My bad, I should have specified. See revised question.

Comment: Have you tried cathing `Floating Point Exception`? [This](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fpectl.html) might help.

Comment: How would that help. FPE is more of an exception (no pun).

Comment: This actually worked anyway. `SIGTERM` also kills the main Python script.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding you but just put all exception causing code in try-except blocks. You seem pretty knowledgeable but I'll give an example anyways

```
try:
    //some potentially error causing code
except (errorType): //need to know what type of exception it will throw
    //code for what to do if the error occurs
```